# Public key extraction from a certificate in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate, digital-certificate, rsacryptoserviceprovider

How to get private key from a x509 v.3 certificate and store it in a `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509certificateobject.PrivateKey;
```

Suppose if you use public key then just change the `.PrivateKey` to `.PublicKey`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509certificateobject.PrivateKey;
```